# How to design a fluid and loosely coupled data UI?

Tags: gui-design, info-visualisation, data-tables

I need some advice with designing a view of a system with the following characteristics:

- Lots of possible data ('label: information')
- Data is quite loosely coupled, but there is some grouping
- Only show data that is filled in

For example:

**Aim**: Show the filled-in information about the customer in a uncluttered/clean view.

**The data:** We have a customer object with a lot of fields. It holds all kinds of information that is loosely grouped together. 25 fields of general information, 10 fields of banking information, 5 fields of personal interests where there are a few lists, and 20 other fields that don't really group anywhere. Almost none of the fields are mandatory, and the customer can have 2 or +50 fields filled in. Some customers only have the banking information filled in, and one of the general fields.

**The problem**:  **How do you keep a nice UI/UX if you can show only the filled in information?** Because you don't really want the page to appear very empty for customers that only filled in a few fields. You don't want to show a information group with a header if it only has a single field, etc, etc. You can't put things in a grid, because there a lists as information fields, etc.

Anyone has experience designing such a system?

Comment: And what is the goal of this interface/screen? Who is going to look this information up and for which purpose?

Comment: It's the view-mode of an ERP tool. So the people viewing the information would be employees of company X, needing to quickly viewing customerdata of company Y.

Comment: They don't need to edit stuff (there is a different GUI for entering data)

Answer (score 1):

just keep all the group under a separate tab in tab menu and keep ungroup attributes under title "addition info(or anything else)". This would be a neat and clean idea to keep all the data separated and easy to understand. Show all the attributes whether it is filled or not. The reason is user would have details that how much fields are remaining to add data. So in future, if they wish, they can add details without knowing the all the attributes how one would get idea that except filled one what are the other attributes. As the number of attributes will be more, user couldn't remember,so keep it

Comment: Problem is that there's so much possibilities, users have to search which elements are already filled in. It's information overload for people not doing data entry.

Comment: @PeterBriers Is there any mandatory and optional type of fields in the form

Comment: Very few are mandatory. 1 or 2 of +50 fields

Answer (score 1):

You could just display a list of the group headings (for those groups that contain data of course):

- Personal
- Banking
- Interests
- etc.

and then expand that selection when it's selected. This could be either replacing the page with the new information or displaying it in a new section opened within the page.

This way the user can see what sort if information is filled in and then drill down to those sections they are interested in. If the section is missing then they know that record doesn't have that information.